# Number of ways of putting $n$ balls into $k$ boxes, with a twist...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Usually, when counting the number of ways in which $n$ balls can be put into $k$ boxes, two cases are considered:

1. Boxes cannot be empty
2. Boxes can be empty

Respectively, each of the listed cases has a formula:

$$C_1={n-1\choose k-1}$$
$$C_2={n+k-1\choose n}$$

This however doesn't suffice my needs. I want the boxes to be all not empty, and be countable, just like in the first case... But I want the boxes to be **indistinguishable**.

That is, as long as you have 4 balls in box 1, 2 balls in box 2, and 1 ball in box 3, it doesn't matter how the boxes themselves are configured or labeled.

For example, if there are 7 balls and 3 boxes, there would be four such ways to arrange them:

1. O|O|OOOOO
2. O|OO|OOOO
3. O|OOO|OOO
4. OO|OO|OOO

I have no ideas how to construct a formula for this

Comment: What you are looking for is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts: https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section03.03.html. This is complicated to solve. I don't believe there is a nice formula for it, but there is a recurrence relation $p_k(n)=p_k(n-k)+p_{k-1}(n-1)$.

Comment: @kccu I didn't recognize this as partitions, wow. But, didn't Ramanujan find an infinite series that converges to the solution of specific partitions? As far as I can remember, that series was very crazy and messy

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, but I wouldn't be surprised if Ramanujan had some sort of result about partitions.

Comment: The generating function for partitions into $k$ parts goes back to Euler. Ramanujan did discover a considerable number of theorems about partitions and partition generating functions.